# Using swap to MERGE (append to) a nested map in a Clojure atom?

Tags: clojure

Let's say I have an atom that contains a map like this:

```
{:count 0 :map hash-map}
```

How can I use swap to merge another key-value pair onto `:map`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'd use `assoc-in`:

```
(swap! my-atom assoc-in [:map :new-key] value)
```

Answer (score 0):

To address the title of the question, you can also merge:

```clj
(def !db (atom {:count 0 :map {:foo :bar}}))

(swap! !db update :map merge {:bar :baz})
=> {:count 0, :map {:bar :baz, :foo :bar}}
```