# How to append to a nested list in a Clojure atom?

Tags: clojure

I want to append a value to a list in a Clojure atom:

```
(def thing (atom {:queue '()}))
```

I know when it's not an atom, I can do this:

```
(concat '(1 2) '(3))
```

How can I translate that into a swap! command?

Note: I asked a similar question involving maps: [Using swap to MERGE (append to) a nested map in a Clojure atom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291076/using-swap-to-merge-append-to-a-nested-map-in-a-clojure-atom)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
user=> (def thing (atom {:queue '()}))
#'user/thing
user=> (swap! thing update-in [:queue] concat (list 1))
{:queue (1)}
user=> (swap! thing update-in [:queue] concat (list 2))
{:queue (1 2)}
user=> (swap! thing update-in [:queue] concat (list 3))
{:queue (1 2 3)}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you write your own fn then it should be side effect free because it may call several time.

```
(def thing (atom {:queue '()})) 

(swap! thing (fn [c]
    (update-in c [:queue] concat '(1 2 3 3))))
```