# Update multiple elements of a Clojure atom within a single swap statement?

Tags: clojure

I have an atom that has two parts to it.

```
(def thing (atom {:queue '() :map {}}))
```

I want to update both :queue and :map in one atomic stroke, to prevent them from getting off-sync.

#### Queue individually:

```
(swap! thing update-in [:queue] (list 1))
```

(From this question: [How to append to a nested list in a Clojure atom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293134/how-to-append-to-a-nested-list-in-a-clojure-atom))

#### Map individually:

```
(swap! thing assoc-in [:map 1] (:key :value))
```

(From this question: [Using swap to MERGE (append to) a nested map in a Clojure atom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291076/using-swap-to-merge-append-to-a-nested-map-in-a-clojure-atom))

How can I do these both within a single swap statement? (assuming that would prevent them from getting off-sync?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have one change you want to make, right? And you could write that change as a pure function? All you need to do is write that function, and pass it as the argument to `swap!`.

```
(defn take-from-queue [{q :queue, m :map}]
  {:queue (rest q), :map (assoc m :new-task (first q))})

(swap! thing take-from-queue)
```

Where of course I have no idea what you actually want the body of your function to do, so I've made up something that doesn't throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a hash-map atom:

```
(def m1 (atom {:a "A" :b "B"}))
```

To change `:a` and `:b` at the same time, changing their values to values that are different, say the numbers 1 and 2, use this function:

```
(defn my-swap! [params]
  (swap! m1 (fn [old new] new) params))
```

, like so:

```
(my-swap! {:a 1 :b 2}) ;=> {:a 1, :b 2}
```

And the same effect could be achieved with the following function and execution:

```
(defn my-multi-swap! [params1 params2]
  (swap! m1 (fn [old new1 new2] new2) params1 params2))

(my-multi-swap! {} {:a 1 :b 2}) ;=> {:a 1, :b 2}
```

Normally `reset!` is used if you want to ignore the old value. Here we use it:

```
(defn my-merge-swap! [params]
  (swap! m1 (fn [old new] (merge old new)) params))

(my-merge-swap! {:b 3}) ;=> {:a "A", :b 3}
```

The first parameter to the *swap! function* is the existing value of the atom, and you must pass in one or more extra parameters, which you can use to give the atom its new value.